# Script to generate insert statements

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write an SQL script to create an insert statement for each row of table TEST which has field `A (int)` and field `B varchar(30)`, in my MS SQL database.

I would like to save those insert statements into a txt file to be able to apply that data back to another database.

Any idea about how to do it?

Comment: What you really need is to [copy data from sql instances](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS478US478&aq=1&oq=SQL%20Server%20data%20migration&sugexp=chrome,mod=6&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=sql%20server%20data%20migration%20tools#hl=en&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS478US478&sclient=psy-ab&q=sql%20server%20data%20copy&oq=sql%20server%20data%20copy&gs_l=serp.3..0i30j0i5i30j0i8i30l2.10016.13164.0.14165.20.20.0.0.0.0.126.1765.15j5.20.0.eiatsh..0.0.P9oZkSAI5qc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=d2003206628f6d70&biw=1920&bih=955) (The first two hits should work: [one](http://stackoverflow.

Answer (score 8):

1. Right-click on your Database in Object Explorer
2. Select **Tasks** -> **Generate Scripts...**
3. In that wizard you will be able to select the desired object(s) that you'd like to script out
4. The next portion has an **Advanced** button, click that
5. Under *General*, you will see the option called **Types of data to script**.  The options are `Schema only`, `Schema and data`, or `Data only`.  I believe you want the last option (Data Only)

Comment: I think that this only works on 2008+.

Comment: +1 Confirmed that this works on 2000 and 2005 instances using 2012 and 2008R2 SSMS.

Answer (score 3):

Why not download SSMS Tools Pack from  http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Download . It easily creates insert scripts. I use it all the time and it is a fabulous tool. Did I mention it is Free!

Comment: It's not free anymore

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [bcp utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802(v=sql.105).aspx) to import or export data.

In your case use something like the following command:

```
bcp "SELECT A, B FROM TEST" queryout Test.txt -c -T
```

To insert data from the file into another table:

```
bcp Database.Schema.Table in Test.txt -T –c
```

Hope this helps as an alternative

Answer (score 0):

I often use a `SELECT` to generate other SQL:

```
select
    'insert dbo.TEST(A, B) values (' + convert(varchar(20), A) + ', ''' + B + ''');'
from dbo.TEST;
```

Save the output and re-use as needed.  If column B contains text delimiters you'll have to deal with this.